Why using helmet return 502?
Nginx configuration file inside /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://47.126.4.133:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}

Import
const express = require('express');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const cors = require('cors');
const { createServer } = require('https');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');

Express configuration
const app = express();
app.set('trust proxy', true);
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors({
    origin: ['https://inswalst.com', 'https://www.inswalst.com'],
    credentials: true
}));
app.use(express.json());

Server configuration
const httpsServer = createServer(
    {
        key: readFileSync('/home/ubuntu/backend/privkey.pem'), 
        cert: readFileSync('/home/ubuntu/backend/fullchain.pem')
    }, 
    app
);

const io = new Server(httpsServer, {
    cors: {
        origin: ['https://inswalst.com', 'https://www.inswalst.com'], 
        credentials: true
    },
    transports: [ 'websocket' ]
});

httpsServer.listen(3001);

Why it return 502 Bad Gateway? How to solve it?
